# How to remove a white space in between the webparts? (Specifically with full width images)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience

I'm not sure if this is a recent SharePoint update, but it wasn't like this before from what I recall since I use full width images all the time.

Like what I said in the title, how do we remove it? See attached screenshot for reference, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you using multiple img elements to display images in a script editor web part/content editor web part?

Comment: I just use the image webpart on the row.

Comment: Are you using wiki page? Could you share the screenshot about these image's element?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wiki page,
[image]

You could click the edit source when you edit the page.You could find the image element like this:

```
<p>​
   <img src="/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/download.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" style="margin: 5px;"/>
   <img src="/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/5db901f4f24f2.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt="" style="margin: 5px;"/>
</p>

 You just need to delete the margin style(margin-top,margin-bottom) and add `style="font-size: 0px;"`to the parent element.   

<p style="font-size: 0px;">
   <img src="/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/download.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt=""/> 
   <img src="/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/5db901f4f24f2.jpg" data-themekey="#" alt=""/>  
</p>
```

Test result:
[image]